# Дженерик методы и верхняя граница

Tags: java, generics

Есть три класса:

```
class A{
}

class B{
}

class Gen<T, V extends T>{
}
```

Следующая программа не скомпилируется:

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Gen<A, B> g;
    }
}
```

ведь `V` обязательно должен быть либо таким же как `T`, либо его подклассом.

Теперь есть такой код:

```
class Main{
    public static <T, V extends T> void qq(T x, V y){
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        qq(new A(), new B());
    }
}
```

Я ожидаю, что он точно так же не скомпилируется, так как `B` не наследуется от `A`, но тем не менее всё отлично работает. **Почему?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `Gen<A, B> g` вы явно указали, что `T=A` и `V=B` - по очевидным причинам это не может скомпилироваться, типы не совместимы.

В `qq(new A(), new B())` вы не указали типов для `qq` *явно*, компилятор делает вывод типов, т.е. находит подходящие. И в этом случае нашел `T=Object` и `V=B`.

Если явно укажите типы `Main.<A, B>qq(new A(), new B())` - получите такую же ошибку.

Comment: а как вы узнали что `T=Object` ? Как это можно проверить ?

Comment: `T=Object` потому, что `Object` единственный тип, который подходит под два ограничения `A extends T` и `B extends T`. Как проверить - я не знаю. Я быстро не нашел опции компилятора, которая бы показывала, как он типы вывел.